# Wrap button in <a> using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there any way to do it? via javascript, i created a `input="image"` and I want to wrap it in an `<a>`, so when I click it, a modal will pop up.

```
 function amphi() {
     amp.setAttribute('type', 'image');
     amp.setAttribute('src', 'baloon.png');
     amp.setAttribute('style', 'position:absolute; left:540px; top:312px; color:red;');
     amp.setAttribute('title', 'Amphitheater');
     amp.setAttribute('ondblclick', 'confirm(`Amphitheater:\n \n \nLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.`);');

     document.body.appendChild(amp);
     hidethis();
     amp.style.visibility = "visible";
 }
```

Comment: post relevant html and css

Comment: This question is very unclear.

Comment: There's no point to doing that, and it's not valid anyway - `<a>` elements cannot contain interactive content (like buttons).

Comment: clear up what you mean by `modal`.   Also, what will using an `<a>` element accomplish that using an `onclick` event won't?   ie `amp.setAttribute('onclick' ...`

Comment: Users will be very surprised if they click in an input box and something pops up. They expect the cursor to be positioned in the box so they can start typing.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

**HTML**

```
<img src="yourbuttonimage.png" onclick="popModal()" />
```

**JS**

```
function popModal(){
    //your modal instantiation script here
}
```